# Sort by hierarchy algorithm

Tags: python, sorting

How can I make this sorting algorithm?

```
modules = {
    2:[4],   # element 2 must be after element 4
    1:[],
    3:[2,4], # element 3 must be after 2 and 3 elements
    4:[1]    # element 4 must be after element 1
}
```

Result `[1, 4, 2, 3]` by conditions.

Comment: If this is HW please tag it as such

Answer (score 4):

That's called a topological sort.  Makefiles do it, and there's a standard UNIX utility called `tsort` that will do it.